# PostgreSQL Database Server Unresponsive

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How do you diagnose problems with PostgreSQL performance?

I have a Django-based webapp using PostgreSQL as a database backend on Ubuntu 12, and under heavy load, the database seems to just disappear, causing the Django-interface to be unreachable and resulting in errors like:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: error with no message from the libpq

django.db.utils.DatabaseError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

What's odd is that the logs in /var/log/postgresql show nothing unusual. The only thing the log /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log shows are lots of lines like:

```
2012-09-01 12:24:01 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

Running `top` shows that PostgreSQL doesn't seem to be consuming any CPU, even though `service postgresql status` indicates it's still running.

Doing a 'service postgresql restart` temporarily fixes the problem, but the problem returns as soon as there's a lot of load on the database.

I've checked the dmesg and syslog, but I don't see anything that would explain what's wrong. What other logs should I check? How do I determine what's wrong with my PostgreSQL server?

Edit: My max_connections is set to 100. Although I am doing a lot of manual transactions. Reading up on Django's ORM behavior with PostgreSQL in manual mode, it looks like I may have to explicitly do connection.close(), which I'm not doing.

Comment: Possibly the maximum connection to the database could be used up, or there are too many connections doing nothing while not beeing closed (timeout set too high).

Comment: Are you on a dedicated server or a VPS?

Comment: @Catcall, KVM-based VPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this was due to Django's buggy Postgres-backend in combination with multi-processing. Essentially, Django doesn't properly close it's connections automatically, causing some weird behavior like tons of "idle in transaction" connections. I fixed it by adding `connection.close()` to the end of my multi-processing launched functions and before certain queries that were throwing this error.

Comment: The problem isn't with django, django doesn't fork the connection so it seems like the process running may close the connection pre-maturely since its shared amongst processes. This is what I had happening. It happend to me when I tried to update the database while multi-procesing. I gathered the data that I want to update and when the multi-processing part was done. I then ran an update query. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
2012-09-01 12:24:01 EDT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

This message shows, so some issue is on client side - maybe some exception from *libpq* ?? There can be related issues - when clients hangs without correct logout, then you have lot of idle connections, and you get other errors early.

Answer (score 1):

The program pg_ctl has some options that *might* help. (`man pg_ctl`)

```
   -c
       Attempt to allow server crashes to produce core files, on platforms
       where this is possible, by lifting any soft resource limit placed
       on core files. This is useful in debugging or diagnosing problems
       by allowing a stack trace to be obtained from a failed server
       process.

   -l filename
       Append the server log output to filename. If the file does not
       exist, it is created. The umask is set to 077, so access to the log
       file is disallowed to other users by default.
```

The program postgres also has some debug options. (`man postgres`)

```
   -d debug-level
       Sets the debug level. The higher this value is set, the more
       debugging output is written to the server log. Values are from 1 to
       5. It is also possible to pass -d 0 for a specific session, which
       will prevent the server log level of the parent postgres process
       from being propagated to this session.
```

In the section "Semi-internal Options" . . .

```
   -n
       This option is for debugging problems that cause a server process
       to die abnormally. The ordinary strategy in this situation is to
       notify all other server processes that they must terminate and then
       reinitialize the shared memory and semaphores. This is because an
       errant server process could have corrupted some shared state before
       terminating. This option specifies that postgres will not
       reinitialize shared data structures. A knowledgeable system
       programmer can then use a debugger to examine shared memory and
       semaphore state.

   -T
       This option is for debugging problems that cause a server process
       to die abnormally. The ordinary strategy in this situation is to
       notify all other server processes that they must terminate and then
       reinitialize the shared memory and semaphores. This is because an
       errant server process could have corrupted some shared state before
       terminating. This option specifies that postgres will stop all
       other server processes by sending the signal SIGSTOP, but will not
       cause them to terminate. This permits system programmers to collect
       core dumps from all server processes by hand.
```